# row number with condition sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
col1    col2                
7       6789      
6       6789      
5       6789      
4       6789      
3       6789      
2       6789      
1       6789      
72      1234      
71      1234      
70      1234      
69      1234      
67      1234      
.        .
.        .
3       1234     
1       1234
```

Aim is to generate row number in sequence (order by col2), so when 1 is found after 72 it must be considered as a sequence, since data would be in a cyclic manner from 1 to 72.

output:

```
col1    col2      col3          
7       6789      79
6       6789      78
5       6789      77
4       6789      76
3       6789      75
2       6789      74
1       6789      73
72      1234      72
71      1234      71
70      1234      70
69      1234      69
67      1234      67
.        .        .
.        .        .
3       1234      3
1       1234      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` with a two-tiered ordering on `col2` followed by `col1`:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2, col1) AS col3
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    col2 DESC,
    col1 DESC;
```